# Create conditional variables grouping by time and id

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a data frame that contains the product and destination (**dest_prod**) consumed by individuals (**id**), observed during different years (**year**) in the data frame **df**:

```
id <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3")
year <- c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2005")
dest_prod <- c("FRA_coke", "FRA_coke", "USA_coke", "FRA_coke+USA_coke", 
               "FRA_coke", "SPA_ham", "FRA_coke+SPA_ham", "GER_coke",
               "CHN_water", "CHN_oil", "CHN_water+CHN_oil+FRA_coke", "CHN_water+CHN_oil+FRA_coke")

df <- data.frame(id, year, dest_prod)
```

I would like to apply the following logic:

1. Create a new variable "new_dest" if an individual consumes a prod_dest in year (t) that comes from a new destination (3 first letters of "dest_prod") than in year (t-1).
2. Create a new variable "new_prod" if an individual consumes a prod_dest in year (t) that contains a new product (letters after the "_" symbol in "dest_prod") than in year (t-1).

**Note!**: If there is no observed year before (t) for a given individual or the last observation comes from 2 years or longer, I will assign "NA" value.

The new dataframe looks like **df_mod**:

```
new_dest <- c("NA", "0", "1", "1",
             "NA", "1", "1", "1",
             "NA", "0", "1", "NA")

new_prod <- c("NA", "0", "0", "0",
             "NA", "1", "1", "0",
             "NA", "1", "1", "NA")

df_mod <- data.frame(id, year, dest_prod, new_dest, new_prod)
```

I have tried to use **ifelse** in dplyr, but it does not work as it is impossible to capture the sense of time and group (id).
Any idea on how to create **new_dest** and **new_prod** in **dplyr**?

Comment: You can use `case_when()` inside a `mutate()` call to evaluate complex conditionals in a vectorized way, and also use `lead()` and `lag()` to look ahead or behind the value of a current row if the condition depends on the previous or next year. But you are making things a lot harder for yourself with the way your data is organized in `dest_prod`. You should tidily separate it into country and product columns (with multiple rows when there are multiple country-product combinations) before doing the comparison.  Otherwise you'll really be fighting the way `dplyr` wants to work.

Comment: `df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(new_dest = substr(dest_prod,1,3),
         new_dest_ind = ifelse(dplyr::lag(new_dest) != new_dest,1,0))` could be a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *do* want to fight the way dplyr wants to work, here's a non-pivot solution :)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>%
  left_join(., mutate(., year = year + 1), by = c('id', 'year'), suffix = c('', '_previous')) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dests = str_extract_all(dest_prod, '\\w{3}_'),
         prods = str_extract_all(dest_prod, '_\\w+'),
         new_dest = max(map_int(dests, \(x) !str_detect(dest_prod_previous, x))),
         new_prod = max(map_int(prods, \(x) !str_detect(dest_prod_previous, x)))) %>%
  select(-c(dests, prods, dest_prod_previous)) %>%
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 12 × 5
#>    id     year dest_prod                  new_dest new_prod
#>    <chr> <dbl> <chr>                         <int>    <int>
#>  1 1      2000 FRA_coke                         NA       NA
#>  2 1      2001 FRA_coke                          0        0
#>  3 1      2002 USA_coke                          1        0
#>  4 1      2003 FRA_coke+USA_coke                 1        0
#>  5 2      2002 FRA_coke                         NA       NA
#>  6 2      2003 SPA_ham                           1        1
#>  7 2      2004 FRA_coke+SPA_ham                  1        1
#>  8 2      2005 GER_coke                          1        0
#>  9 3      2001 CHN_water                        NA       NA
#> 10 3      2002 CHN_oil                           0        1
#> 11 3      2003 CHN_water+CHN_oil+FRA_coke        1        1
#> 12 3      2005 CHN_water+CHN_oil+FRA_coke       NA       NA
```

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to parse the `dest_prod` column into a usable format:

```r
library(tidyverse)

parsed <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(c("id", "year"), as.integer) %>% 
  separate_rows(dest_prod, sep = "[+]") %>% 
  separate(dest_prod, into = c("dest", "prod"))

parsed
#> # A tibble: 18 × 4
#>       id  year dest  prod 
#>    <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#>  1     1  2000 FRA   coke 
#>  2     1  2001 FRA   coke 
#>  3     1  2002 USA   coke 
#>  4     1  2003 FRA   coke 
#>  5     1  2003 USA   coke 
#>  6     2  2002 FRA   coke 
#>  7     2  2003 SPA   ham  
#>  8     2  2004 FRA   coke 
#>  9     2  2004 SPA   ham  
#> 10     2  2005 GER   coke 
#> 11     3  2001 CHN   water
#> 12     3  2002 CHN   oil  
#> 13     3  2003 CHN   water
#> 14     3  2003 CHN   oil  
#> 15     3  2003 FRA   coke 
#> 16     3  2005 CHN   water
#> 17     3  2005 CHN   oil  
#> 18     3  2005 FRA   coke
```

Then:

```r
parsed %>% 
  # Add previous year's data in a list column
  nest_join(
    mutate(., year = year + 1L),
    name = "previous",
    by = c("id", "year")
  ) %>% 
  # Check if any dest/prod appeared in previous year
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    new_dest = !dest %in% previous$dest,
    new_prod = !prod %in% previous$prod,
  ) %>% 
  # Set to missing if previous year was not observed
  mutate(
    across(c(new_dest, new_prod), replace, !nrow(previous), NA)
  ) %>% 
  # Aggregate indicators on year level
  group_by(id, year) %>% 
  summarise(
    new_dest = any(new_dest),
    new_prod = any(new_prod),
  )
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>       id  year new_dest new_prod
#>    <int> <int> <lgl>    <lgl>   
#>  1     1  2000 NA       NA      
#>  2     1  2001 FALSE    FALSE   
#>  3     1  2002 TRUE     FALSE   
#>  4     1  2003 TRUE     FALSE   
#>  5     2  2002 NA       NA      
#>  6     2  2003 TRUE     TRUE    
#>  7     2  2004 TRUE     TRUE    
#>  8     2  2005 TRUE     FALSE   
#>  9     3  2001 NA       NA      
#> 10     3  2002 FALSE    TRUE    
#> 11     3  2003 TRUE     TRUE    
#> 12     3  2005 NA       NA
```